# I am migrating my asp.net web api to asp.net core. Cors migration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, migration, cors

In my asp.net project i have defined cors in webapiconfig file like this

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // New code
            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*", "DataServiceVersion, MaxDataServiceVersion") { SupportsCredentials = true };
            config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Now I want to migrate it to asp.net core. How can it be done? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add the CORS services:

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", builder =>
       {
           builder
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowCredentials()
               .WithExposedHeaders("DataServiceVersion", "MaxDataServiceVersion");
       }));
   }
   ```
2. Use the CORS middleware:

   ```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
   {
       app.UseCors("AllowAll");
   }
   ```

Comment: Still error occurs => No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5004' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Comment: @SagarChaudhary Is the `UseCors` extension method called before the `UseMvc` method `app.UseCors("AllowAll").UseMvc();`?

Comment: yes  
            app.UseIdentity();
            app.UseCors("AllowAll");
            app.UseMvc();